# Android Tab that makes http request and stores response

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-tabhost

To clarify the title of this question, I have an android application that is communicating with a WCF restful webservice. At a certain part of the application the user can select from 3 tabs each displaying data obtained from a call to the webservice. Ideally I would like to store or cache this information after the first call (as opposed to making the call everytime the user switches tabs)

My question is kind of a 2 parter because I haven't decided the best way to implement the tabs  (should I use fragments?) in the first place but would like to select the best design based upon the desired functionality.

My question is, what is the best way to implement a tabbed activity where each tab makes a separate http request and stores the response (response will be displayed in a listview)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement ViewPager using fragments (here is an example : http://tamsler.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-viewpager-and-fragments.html)
2. In your Fragments, use an asynctask that makes a call to IgnitedHttp methods to retrieve data from your endpoints.  (see [How to use Ignition HTTP classes to make Get request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001545/how-to-use-ignition-http-classes-to-make-get-request/11002467#11002467) )  This will create a cache of the responses on the android device that will save you from having to get the same data over and over again. (asyncTask example : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Do you know anything about the IgnitionHTTP license? I'd rather not use anything that could cause licensing problems down the road.

Comment: license is Apache 2.0 (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)   here is the project page https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition